# Identifying potential implicit conversions across databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I modify the following query to Identify possible implicit conversions (for columns that share the same name) across databases?

What I currently have works, but only for whatever database you are currently in.

What I would like is to see all the potential matches for each database on the same server. Here is what I'm currently working with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        @@SERVERNAME AS [server_name] ,
        DB_NAME() AS [database_name] ,
        [left].[COLUMN_NAME] AS [column_name] ,
        [left].[TABLE_SCHEMA] AS [table_schema] ,
        [left].[TABLE_NAME] AS [table_name] ,
        [left].[DATA_TYPE] AS [data_type] ,
        [left].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] AS [character_maximum_length] ,
        [left].[NUMERIC_PRECISION] AS [numeric_precision] ,
        [left].[NUMERIC_SCALE] AS [numeric_scale]
FROM    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] [left]
        INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] [right] ON [left].[COLUMN_NAME] = [right].[COLUMN_NAME]
WHERE   ( ( [left].[DATA_TYPE] != [right].[DATA_TYPE] )
          OR ( [left].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] != [right].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] )
          OR ( [left].[NUMERIC_PRECISION] != [right].[NUMERIC_PRECISION] )
          OR ( [left].[NUMERIC_SCALE] != [right].[NUMERIC_SCALE] )
        )
ORDER BY [left].[COLUMN_NAME] ,
        [left].[TABLE_SCHEMA] ,
        [left].[TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: You mean db on the same server?

Comment: That is correct. I'll update my question to make that more clear.

Comment: Just a tip: In your `INNER JOIN ON ....` include `AND [left].[TABLE_NAME] <> [right].[TABLE_NAME]` to avoid self compare.

Comment: Just add a `<database>.` to get the schema for any particular database.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't offer similar views covering all databases on a server.